# I Can't Getr my PN532 NFC Module to work with Raspberry PI2

Tags: pi-2, rpi.gpio, rfid

I have a Raspberry PI 2 and a PN532 NFC Module, but I can't read it I keep getting this errors when I run nfc-list:

```
error libnfc.driver.pn532_spi Unable to wait for SPI data. (RX)   pn53x_check_communication: Timeout error libnfc.driver.pn532_spi Unable to wait for SPI data.   (RX) nfc-list: ERsROR: Unable to open NFC device: pn532_spi:/dev/spidev0.0:500000
```

I have already enabled SPI through `raspi-config`.

[image: My Connection]

Blue Cable = SDA
GREEN Cable = SCL
ORANGE Cable = 5V
YELLOW Cable = GND

Thanks,

Felipe

Comment: SPI mode or I2c  mode , you active SPI mode but use i2c mode ?!!   [tuterial](https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-nfc-minecraft-blocks/hardware-wiring)

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Change cable as follows :

[image]

more details
[tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-nfc-minecraft-blocks/hardware-wiring)